# RoutingError in JavaScript folder after upgrading from Rails 3.1 to Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just updated to Rails 3.2 and I started to get errors like this:

```
Started GET "/javascripts/application.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-02-20 23:25:10 +0800

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/javascripts/application.js"):
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /home/alex/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /home/alex/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.8ms)
```

The same for post.js, page.js etc...But all these files are in the `assets/javascripts` folder.

What exactly I have to do in order to fix this?

This is how I'm including them:

```
 <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

**application.rb:**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

require "sprockets/railtie"

if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

module Sandbox3Devise
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
    # config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)

    # Only load the plugins named here, in the order given (default is alphabetical).
    # :all can be used as a placeholder for all plugins not explicitly named.
    # config.plugins = [ :exception_notification, :ssl_requirement, :all ]

    # Activate observers that should always be running.
    # config.active_record.observers = :cacher, :garbage_collector, :forum_observer

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
    config.encoding = "utf-8"

    # Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]

    # Enable the asset pipeline
    config.assets.enabled = true

    # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
    config.assets.version = '1.0'
  end
end
```

**development.rb:**

```
Sandbox3Devise::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Expands the lines which load the assets
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Which version did you upgrade from? Rails 3.1 introduced the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), a new way of organizing assets (images, stylesheets, javascripts, among others). Seems like you have to do the transition : the guide linked above is a good place to start.

** In the `config/application.rb`, is the line `require "sprockets/railtie"` present ? if not, you should add it.

**** (Second edit) : So instead of `javascripts/application.js?body=1`, you should have `assets/application.js?body=1`. This can be set with `config.assets.prefix = "/some_other_path"`. It doesn't look like it's been changed in the files you pasted though, so this might still not be it, and in this case.. I give up. :p

Comment: Thanks, I added that but same problem :(

Comment: In case you didn't, you have to restart the server. What I see here, is that your app is not using the asset pipeline, because of the `?body=1`. This is no longer done by the asset pipeline, it uses fingerprinting instead. I had the same problem, solved it with the railtie issue. If it's really not this, then I'm missing something. Can you paste your application.rb and development.rb files ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. OK, I edited my question with the files. I did restart the server.

Comment: I think I give up too. I will just install a new Rails 3.2 app and copy paste the files of the previous one.

Comment: Adding "sprockets/railtie" worked for me.  I was upgrading from Rails 3.1.1, but the application started out life somewhere around Rails 3.1 rc3 and was missing this line in application.rb.  Thanks @ksol!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to add an answer to this old question, it's mainly for the benefit of those (like myself) who will stumble across this thread.

I've had this issue also. I didn't upgrade, I started my application as a rails3 application and after a while, this sort of issue occurred. I think the cause was when I started messing around with gems, such as Faye, bootstrap-wysihtml5 etc that required jquery references amongst the application.js and applicaion.css files. (that's how it appears in my version control logs)

Anyway, to solve the issue, I just created a new rails application and copied the app, config, db and gems over. This resolved every issue the rails server was logging, so it might be a bug with the asset pipeline. I included the `require "sprockets/railtie"`line in application.rb for good measure, as suggested above also.